# Wordpress doesn't interpret html tag in blogpost

Tags: php, html, wordpress, tags

When I add a youtube video using tinymce plugin in wordpress, it works great in the visual editor part.

But in my custom template, It just shows

```
[embed]https://youtube.com/my-video-link[/embed]
```

Sorry maybe there is an obvious answer but I'm totally new with wordpress and google just gave me the opposite I want with answers about how to escape html from blog post content..

I don't know what I have missed but thank you advance in advance

**EDIT**

I don't use `the_content()` function to echo my post_content but I try and it works so this function must use a function to transform my embed tag in a youtube iframe.
Because I need to get the last post from certain category I store the
`get_posts(['category_name' => 'My Category Name', 'showpost' => 1])` in a variable then I do `$mySpecificCategory[0]->post_content`. In fact I don't know if it's the good way.

**SOLUTION**

Ok so I find the solution on the [wordpress support](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/call-function-called-by-embed-shortcode-direct?replies=8). Which is:

```
<?php echo apply_filters( 'the_content',  $mySpecificCategory[0]->post_content) ?>
```

Comment: Can you share your exact URL format?  Looking at the [oembed code](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.1/src/wp-includes/class-oembed.php#L30), the URL needs to have a `watch` or `playlist` in the URL, unless you're using the `youtu.be` domain.  If you mean you have `[embed]https://youtube.com/my-video-link[/embed]` as literal text in your template's PHP file, you'll need to run it through the [`do_shortcode`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode) function and `echo` the result

Comment: So I add a new media from a web address in the editor. This is the link format I use: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/BEG-ly9tQGk" but it also works with https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BEG-ly9tQGk. When I say "it works" it's because I have a preview in the article editor. No matter the link it just shows [embed]https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BEG-ly9tQGk[/embed] on the blog post page. But I'll try do_shortcode. Notice that I have other text and html code in my post content, not only the [embed] tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

Ok so I find the solution on the [wordpress support](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/call-function-called-by-embed-shortcode-direct?replies=). Which is:

```
<?php echo apply_filters( 'the_content',  $mySpecificCategory[0]->post_content) ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `do_shortcode()` function to transform embed tag into youtube iframe:

```
echo do_shortcode( $content );
```

Check http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode for more details

Comment: Ok so I try but it doesn't show anything.
I open my console to see html rendered but nothing at all. I even try to put a random link just like this <?php echo do_shortcode( '[embed]https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BEG-ly9tQGk[/embed]' ) ?> but nothing. So what did I miss ? And i repeat that in my post_content value I don't only have the embed code, I also have text and html tag

Answer (score 0):

Content with shortcodes replaced by the output from the shortcode's handler(s).

Examples

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'do_shortcode', 11 ); // From shortcodes.php

// Use shortcode in a PHP file (outside the post editor).

echo do_shortcode( '[gallery]' );

// In case there is opening and closing shortcode.

echo do_shortcode( '[iscorrect]' . $text_to_be_wrapped_in_shortcode . '[/iscorrect]' );

// Use shortcodes in text widgets.

add_filter( 'widget_text', 'do_shortcode' );

// Use shortcodes in form like Landing Page Template.

echo do_shortcode( '[contact-form-7 id="91" title="quote"]' );

// Store the short code in a variable.

$var = do_shortcode( '[gallery]' );

echo $var;
```